# grails countrySelect tag  -  default value

Tags: grails

The [countrySelect tag](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/countrySelect.html) says it has the following attribute:

- default (optional) - The ISO code of the default country to display if value is not set

I removed the value attribute altogether, and still can't get it to display "United States" as the default selection when I do:

```
  <g:countrySelect name="ship.country" default="usa" />

     or

  <g:countrySelect name="ship.country" default="United States" />
```

What am I doing wrong .. what else should I try?

Thanks

Comment: which versin of Grails are u running?! 1.3.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<g:countrySelect name="ship.country" default="usa" />
```

Must work! i just tested in my grails 1.3.7 ! and it worked perfectly!

What is the version of grails that you re using?

Comment: That's strange, I'm using grails 1.3.7.  I just tried it as a stand-alone / single element in a test page, and it worked.  Hmm.  I wonder what's wrong with my real page.  I'll just cut it down to nothing and figure out what it is.  Thanks for your response Aurthur.

Comment: I had a CSS error I didn't see and it caused it somehow.  Thanks again.

Comment: Worked for me too. I'm in fact using it in our app.